# Getting a diamond shape watermark on my Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js

I am using Vue.js with vue-google-maps and I am getting a diamond shape watermark on the map. I reched out to google support and they confirmed it is only happening within my tool thus it is either vue or vue-google-maps. Does anyone have any way to remove this?

here is a screen shot of the watermark
[image]

Comment: I'd start by right-clicking, "inspect element", and see what that reveals. It definitely won't be Vue doing it. Can you provide a live link to an example of the issue for us to see?

Comment: You might get better answers from vue-google-maps themselves if you go to their github and report the bug there.

Comment: @CyclopeanCity I have created an issue on the github page. Unfortunately this does not have a lot of support from the developer at this time.

Comment: @ceejayoz it appears to possibly be the borders of the tiles

Comment: @Jason Then I'd be looking into your CSS for `border-radius` calls.

Comment: I am trying but its difficult with google maps

Comment: Not Google's CSS, yours. I suspect you have some CSS that's too broad that's inadvertently being applied to the embedded map, as this definitely isn't something Google (nor a mapping plugin like vue-google-maps) would've built in by default.

Comment: @ceejayoz found it. you were correct. it was my css. sometimes we complete overlook the obvious. Thank you. Make this an answer and I will accept it. BTW: do you have any insight on how I can add the border radius to my custom icon images?

Comment: @Jason You'd need to give the icons a class (or find an existing class already on them) to target your CSS to.

Comment: @ceejayoz, ya, I can't find a way to ad a class is the problem

Comment: Well, then you should update your question with the code for the icons, as none are shown in your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are waiting for the solution:

```
#google-maps-container img {
    border-radius: 0;
}
```